# purpose of Funnel in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

[image: NiFi UI - Screenshot]

In the image, there are 3 **GenerateFlowFile** processors connected to a **LogAttribute** processor. I would like to know the need for Funnel. Please clarify.

I understood one such use of funnel where it can be used to merge components from two different process group as described in this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMUS28Y8Pro) video.

Comment: in queue you could manage the priority of flow files. after funnel you have one queue and you are able to manage the priority of all incoming dataflows.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, imagine having 20 of those `GenerateFlowFile` processors. Imagine having to replace the `LogAttribute` processor with a different processor. It would be a hard job doing this since they are connected directly to the `LogAttribute` processor. However, if you had a Funnel between them, you would only need to replace the destination of the Funnel and not all of the processors.

I also use it for debugging flows. When I need a quick destination to test the intermediate result of a flow.

Basically what a Funnel does, is to just transfer FlowFiles forward as it gets them.

Comment: +1. Rather than creating a process group for these, funnel would come handy. I learned this later after having Process groups created for my needs, and now changing them to funnel ( at least, this fits perfectly in my use case). Although, we also need to determine based on the use cases.